# SSRS Reports are not working post TLS 1.2

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We are facing an issue related to `SSRS Report` post-TLS 1.2 Enabled in our servers.

Error:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---&gt; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes. We fixed it by enabling FIPS Algorithm

Answer (score 0):

We work able to fix the problem by adding the following code to our C# application:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```